# How limit a view to show only a single type of row without limiting rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL view that has a data structure like this:

```
/==========================================\
| row_id | user_id | page_id | permissions |
|========|=========|=========|=============|
| 1      | 1       | test1   | 011         |
| 2      | 2       | test1   | 111         |
| 3      | 2       | test2   | 111         |
| 4      | 2       | test3   | 111         |
| 5      | 3       | test2   | 001         |
\==========================================/
```

The problem is that I really only want someone to request the data for a maximum of 1 user ID. A user ID may only have 1 row associated with it, or it could have hundreds.

**My Question:** How do I limit a view to only show data for a single user ID?

---

Actual view SQL: (produced by PHPMyAdmin)

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `endpoint_permission_sets` AS
    SELECT
        `u`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
        `p`.`id` AS `permission_id`,
        `p`.`endpoint` AS `endpoint`,
        `p`.`individual_permissions` AS `individual_permissions`,
        `p`.`collection_permissions` AS `collection_permissions`,
        `p`.`global_permissions` AS `global_permissions`
    FROM (
        (
            `other_schema`.`users` `u`
            LEFT JOIN `endpoint_groups` `g`
                ON (((`u`.`endpoint_group_id` = `g`.`id`) AND (`g`.`is_active` = 1)))
        )
        LEFT JOIN `endpoint_permissions` `p`
            ON ((
                ((`g`.`id` = `p`.`group_id`) OR (`u`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id`))
                AND (`p`.`is_active` = 1)
            ))
    );
```

Comment: Perhaps instead use a sproc, that takes `user_id` as a parameter?

Comment: Perhaps, I will have to research what exactly that would look like. If it looks like that is the best course of action, I will let you know and you can upgrade this comment to an answer.

Comment: Or, if the `user_id` to which the resultset should be limited can somehow be determined by the logged in (MySQL) user's credentials, you could do that...?

Comment: no, user_id does not line up to a MySQL user.

Comment: @eggyal Go ahead and upgrade your comment to an answer. After researching how stored procedures work, they are intended to support exactly this type of behavior.